# Posting an array to the database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

Article

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
  has_many :comments
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :article_tags
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

ArticleTag

```
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Tag

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :article_tags
 has_many :articles, :through => :article_tags
end
```

This is how i am getting the tags in the .

```
@article = params[:article]
@tags = params[:tag_ids]
```

Now the real problem comes with posting the article into the articles table as well as the posting the tags associated with the various articles into the article_tags table.

Update

I am using simple_form_for gem which allows me to create a multi-select in bootstrap using the association method so the problem is not getting the tags into the form but rather posting them into the database(creating new rows for the article_tags). I want to be able to retrieve them via `@article.article_tags`. This is what is was trying but i don't know if it is right.

```
@article_params = params[:article]
  article_params[:tag_ids].each do |tag|
  @article_tag =    @article.article_tags.build('article_id'=>@article.id,'tag_id'=>tag)
      @article_tag.save
end

def article_params
params.require(:article).permit(:title,:category_id,:text,     :photo,:tag_ids => [])
end
```

This has to be done as the article is being created it's like posting to two tables at the same time in the same method ie the articles and article_tags tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [concept of nested attributes in rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to solve this.

You can find an example/Explanation [on this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

When you use nested attributes, you won't need to separately get the `articles` and `tags` in your controller, and then worry about saving these, rails will automatically handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If you want to associate existing `tags` to the new `article`, you'll just need to populate `tag_ids`
2. If you want to create *new* `tags`, you'll have to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

---

**Existing Tags**

Adding existing tags to an article is simple:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :article_tags

  validates :title, :text, presence: true #-> declare multiple validations on same line
end

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @article = Article.new article_params
      @article.save
   end

   private

   def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(tag_ids: [])
   end
end
```

Use the [`collection_singular_ids`](https://ernie.io/2010/10/02/the-underused-collection_singular_ids-method/) attribute to assign "join" records in your parent:

```
#app/views/articles/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allocate any `tag` to your new `article`, however, it will *not* allow you to create new tags.

---

**New Tags**

If you wished to create new tags with your `article`, you'll have to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html):

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @article = Article.new
     @article.tags.build
   end

   def create
     @article = Article.new article_params
     @article.save
   end

   private

   def article_params
     params.require(:article).permit(tags_attributes: [:name])
   end
end

#app/views/articles/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
      <%= t.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will create new tags an automatically associate them with your new `article`.

Comment: Updated the question